# How to test that Bazel my_test rule fails when it should?

Tags: unit-testing, bazel, bazel-rules

I have found the [documentation for how to test for expected **analysis phase** errors](https://bazel.build/rules/testing#failure-testing), but I'm drawing a blank no mater what I try to search for on how to test for expected **execution phase** failures.

---

An example of what I'm looking for would be a test of [this example `line_length_test` rules](https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples/blob/main/rules/test_rule/line_length.bzl) where the test feeds in a file with over length lines and expects the test-under-test to be run and produce a failure.

Or to put it another way; I want a test that would fail if I did something dumb like this:

```
def _bad_test_impl(ctx):
  # No-op, never fails regardless of what you feed it.

  executable = ctx.actions.declare_file(ctx.label.name + ".sh")
  ctx.actions.write(output=executable, content="")
  return [DefaultInfo(executable=executable)]

bad_test = rule(
  implementation=_bad_test_impl,
  test=True,
)
```

---

**Edit:**

So far, the best I've come up with is the very gross:

### `BUILD`

```
# Failure
bad_test(
  name = "bad_test_fail_test",
  tags = ["manual"],
)

native.sh_test(
  name = "bad_test_failure_test",
  srcs = [":not.sh"],
  args = ["$(location :bad_test_fail_test)"],
  data = [":bad_test_fail_test"],
)
```

### `not.sh`

```
! $*
```

This does *not* seem like a good idea, particularly for something I'd expect to be well supported.

---

### EDIT:

I got annoyed and [built my own](https://github.com/bcsgh/bazel_rules/blob/master/tests/fail_test.bzl). I **still** wish there was [official implementation](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/issues/419).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that your `not.sh` is a particularly bad solution. But it depends on the situation. In general the Key to good failure testing is specificity i.e. this test should fail for this specific reason. If you don't get this nailed down your going to have a lot of headaches with false positives.

I'll use a slightly more expressive example to try and illustrate why it's so difficult to create a "generic/well supported" failure testing framework.

Let's say that we are developing a compiler. To test the compilers parser we intentionally feed the compiler a malformed source file, and we expect it to fail with something like a "missed semicolon on line 55". But instead our compiler fails from a fairly nasty bug that results in a segfault. As we have just tested that the compiler fails, the test passes.

This kind of a false positive is really hard to deal with in a way that is easy to reason about, whilst also being generic.

What we really want in the above scenario, is to test that the compiler fails AND it prints "missed semicolon on line 55". At this point it becomes increasingly difficult to create a "well supported" interface for these kinds of tests.

In reality a failure test is an integration test, or in some cases an end to end test.

Here is a short excerpt of an [integration test from the Bazel repository](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/09c621e4cf5b968f4c6cdf905ab142d5961f9ddc/src/test/shell/integration/sandboxfs_test.sh#L101-L104). This integration test calls Bazel with a range of different flags some combinations expecting success and others failure;

```bash
function test_explicit_sandboxfs_not_found() {
  create_hello_package

  bazel build \
    --experimental_use_sandboxfs \
    --experimental_sandboxfs_path="/non-existent/sandboxfs" \
    //hello >"${TEST_log}" 2>&1 && fail "Build succeeded but should have failed"

  expect_log "Failed to get sandboxfs version.*/non-existent/sandboxfs"
}
```

And the [corresponding build definition](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/09c621e4cf5b968f4c6cdf905ab142d5961f9ddc/src/test/shell/integration/BUILD#L704-L710);

```py
sh_test(
    name = "sandboxfs_test",
    size = "medium",
    srcs = ["sandboxfs_test.sh"],
    data = [":test-deps"],
    tags = ["no_windows"],
)
```

Comment: I don't disagree with any of that, but it doesn't address my question either. `not.sh` is not intended to be a good test (and isn't), just a "simplest thing that might work". What I'm hoping for is something that's maintained by the people who own the custom rules infrastructure. What I'd *like* is a rule that can be fed a label for a test rule (that would fail at in the execution phase) along with a list of patterns to check the output log for. That seems like something that should already exist, without me having to build my own.

Comment: Fair enough. As far as I know, what you are describing in this comment doesn't exist and you might have to write your own.